# Print the index.php code instead of execute in magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, ubuntu, index.php

I have installed magento 2 in my ubuntu and I tried to run magento setup, it print the index.php code.

Help me.

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 possibilities:

**1. You don't have PHP installed. In that case run:**

```
sudo apt-get install php php-mysql
```

**2. You have PHP installed but not enabled. You can try running:**

```
sudo a2enmod php7  
sudo service apache2 restart
```

**3. You have PHP installed and enabled but you haven't restarted apache.**

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Thanks for response, I will check and let you know.

Comment: Hi, I tried your instructions
Everything is well. But I tried to run the page again, shown localhost is currently unable to handle this request. (HTTP ERROR 500).

Comment: try to sudo chmod -R 777 /"your files location"

Answer (score 0):

if you have above answer, depending on which magento 2 version you are trying to install.

for e.g. if you are going with > 2.3 you must be needing php

~7.1.3
~7.2.0.

if that's not the case with you, then coming towards your 500 error. which usually means something is not right with the code.
the possible url might not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible issue could be the missing modules. Try executing below (If your PHP version is 7.4)

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.4

sudo service apache2 restart
```